Finding the number of cycle in a simple graph
Given a simple graph, output the number of simple cycles in it. A simple cycle is a cycle with no repeated vertices or edges.
Input:
The first line of input contains two integers n and m (1 ≤ n ≤ 19, 0 ≤ m) – respectively the number of vertices and edges of the graph. Each of the subsequent m lines contains two integers a and b, (1 ≤ a, b ≤ n, a ≠ b) indicating that vertices a and b are connected by an undirected edge. There is no more than one edge connecting any pair of vertices.
Output:
Output the number of cycles in the given graph.
Don't understand how dynamic programming and bitmasking working here.

To me it's not clear how this relates to Dynamic Programming and bitmasking; please clarify.
